# File Upload from Android to Django results in empty request.FILES dictionary

Tags: java, android, python, django, http

I'm having trouble uploading an image file (jpg format) from the sdcard on an Android device over to a Django server. As far as I can tell I'm doing all the standard things on both ends, and believe that I have followed the cautions and caveats I'm reading all over the web (SO and otherwise).

Here's what I'm doing on Android (calling this from an AsyncTask - not shown, but confirmed working through print statements in the program I'm running):

```
public static boolean uploadFile(String path, String serverURL) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost        post   = new HttpPost( serverURL );
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
    entity.addPart( "file", new FileBody((new File(path)), "image/jpeg" ));
    post.setEntity( entity );
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, response.getStatusLine().toString());
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString( response.getEntity(), "UTF-8" );
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, responseText);
        return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return false;
}
```

And here's the Django side, in views.py (the one I'm calling by URL is upload_photo):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import simplejson

from photos.models import Photo

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the photos index.")

@csrf_exempt
def upload_photo(request):
    title1 ='test'
    new_image = Photo(title=title1, photo=request.FILES['file'], description='')
    new_image.save()
    response_data=[{"success": "1"}]
    #return HttpResponse(request.body) -- do this to see the raw packet format of the request, just as a sanity check. It returns the response shown in the next code section.
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
```

I have a model called Photo (called above, but not shown) which is meant to save the image file that's uploaded. Passing it an argument of the file (request.FILES['file']) fails though, as shown below.

The Java program gets back a 500 error, printing the following traceback from Django's response:

```
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049): HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049): Traceback (most recent call last):
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):   File "/mit/eliasb/Scripts/django/me/server/photos/views.py", line 13, in upload_photo
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):     new_image = Photo(title=title1, photo=request.FILES['file'], description='')
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 258, in __getitem__
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049):     raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))
01-13 14:30:21.070: D/FileUpload(2049): MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'file' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>"
```

It seems that the dictionary of files is empty. Why is this?

---

**Appendix below. The above fully describes my question, but for reference here are some more things I've tried.**

When I uncomment that second-to-last line in the Django view (to print the raw request data), here's what it sends back (a bit of HTTP header stuff and then a whole lot of binary JPEG data).

```
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): --WZ4aemH--fFnroCDynihK_UAeUSUfzOUO3
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): 
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): ���ၱExif����MM��*��������
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): ����������������������������������������(��������������2���������������������������������������1�������������i������������Ո%�����������������i������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������H������������H������2014:01:13 13:54:08��Google��Glass 1��Glass-1 XE12 947604����!�����������0220������������������������������������������������������������������������   �������������@�������������������������������"���������������'����������D�������
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): ����������������������������
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): ��������������
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): ��������������������������������������ǒ������������������������������   ���������� �����
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): ������������Ϣ������������ע������������ߣ���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������  �����������������
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): �����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������B��B@�������������d�������������������������d����������������������������
01-13 13:54:14.872: D/FileUpload(8930): �������������d������������������'������d�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������h����������������������������������������(���������������������������������������@|��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������H������������H����������    �JFIF������������BCEEFEEEEIFFJHKIJJIIJNKKJNLMOOMMMOMOONPOPRQSRPTRSRURSUVSTUVUVUUXVWWXWVYXXXZYYYXYZZY\[Z[\[[\\[]
```

So clearly the server is getting the file data, just not putting it into the request.FILES dictionary. I even tried parsing out just the section of request.content that has the bytes of file contents, and writing them to disk, but this just yields a corrupted JPEG file that can't be opened.

It seems like what I'm doing is very similar to what this person did: [Upload a file with Android to Django web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447299/upload-a-file-with-android-to-django-web-service).

I've followed advice from elsewhere of making sure to encode my form as enctype="multipart/form-data" (through an Apache HTTP API call, as well as using the parameter  HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE rather than HttpMultipartMode.STRICT as described here: http://www.radomirml.com/blog/2009/02/13/file-upload-with-httpcomponents-successor-of-commons-httpclient/ - though for me they have the same effect.)

I've tried using Apache's sample code here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java,
but I get an exception on this line: `CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();`

```
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:217)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:487)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:147)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:136)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:112)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:727)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at sethberg.glass.me.FileUpload.uploadFile(FileUpload.java:26)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at sethberg.glass.me.FileUploadTask.doInBackground(FileUploadTask.java:24)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at sethberg.glass.me.FileUploadTask.doInBackground(FileUploadTask.java:1)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:273)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     ... 5 more
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     ... 16 more
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
01-13 14:50:54.251: E/AndroidRuntime(4448):     ... 19 more
```

Any pointers here? Both the Python and Java sides to this seem straightforward. The Java code seems to me more suspect just since it's longer, and there's practically nothing to change on the Django side - just grab what's in `request.FILES`... the file size is less than 2.5 MB (it's closer to 1 MB) which I understand is the maximum size Django's willing to handle? Or is that just for saving files to disk rather than receiving their contents?